# Synonymize [paradigms] and [programming-paradigms]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

The tags [paradigms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paradigms) (144) and [programming-paradigms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-paradigms) (105) cover the same topic. [Both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242177) [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641580) [contain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2078978) [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1784664) [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23277) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/232884). The tags themselves are not off-topic and should not be burninated.

I don't have the prerequisites necessary to propose a synonym request, so if those who do or a willing mod could do so, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I presume the target tag would be [programming-paradigms]? (By the way, as it might be expected [programming-paradigms] seems tidier than [paradigms] at the moment.)

Comment: I disagree, @duplode. I'd say the master tag should be [paradigms]. The "programming" part is implicit and therefore redundant on a programming Q&A site.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, say that to the people asking [general computing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debian%20or%20ubuntu%20or%20windows%20or%20linux?mode=all). If you can be explicit, why should we avoid it? What is there to lose?

Comment: Those people can't be helped, @Braiam, no matter what we name the tags. Why clutter things up for everyone else?

Comment: @CodyGray what is being cluttered? You will have 1 tag less.

Comment: The addition of "-programming" to the name of the tag. You could do that for just about every tag on the site, and there's just no reason. I don't want to see [windows-programming], [debian-programming], etc. It takes up a lot of room in the tags field, and woe is everyone if the tag becomes popular enough to be automatically prepended to the front of every question using it. I just don't see the merit in adding it. If you don't have a clue what the purpose of this site is yet, you won't get that clue when applying tags.

Comment: @CodyGray well, that is the same thing we do with other tags: to python libraries we suffix python-, with apache products we suffix apache-, etc, I don't know why are you against that. Every tag which isn't clear what it is for from the upfront, is prone to being misused. Also, your concept of clutter seems to be very sketchy.

Comment: We do it in cases where the tag *needs to be disambiguated*. There is nothing ambiguous about [paradigms] here. If we were talking about Python paradigms, then we'd need a prefix. Or if the tag referred specifically to OOP paradigms. But we don't need a prefix when it refers to *programming* paradigms, since everything on this site is programming-related. There is literally nothing unclear about what the tag might mean. In general, shorter tags are better than longer tags, unless you specifically need the length to disambiguate two things with a similar name.

Comment: @CodyGray why wait until then when we can prevent it now?

Comment: You want to preemptively disambiguate things? That's ridiculous. We don't even know what we're disambiguating it *against*. Furthermore, a "programming" prefix is not disambiguation on a Q&A site about programming. The ambiguity is not going to be with a future tag called [philosophical-paradigms] or whatever, it's going to be with *specific types* of programming paradigms, in which case, [programming-paradigms] does nothing to disambiguate.

Comment: @CodyGray why not? I mean, what's your problem with not wasting time later?

Answer (score 1):

Done. Since I still [agree with myself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342869/synonymize-paradigms-and-programming-paradigms#comment442081_342869), [programming-paradigms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-paradigms) has been merged into [paradigms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paradigms) and a synonym has been created.

Answer (score -5):

[programming-paradigms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-paradigms) should be the main tag. The name of the tag is of utmost importance. Being explicitly about which kind of paradigms are we talking about, is preferred in the long run. There's no downsides to be verbose about it. We have many people asking non-programming questions on a site that is about programming. If doesn't result immediately obvious that this site is about programming questions, it makes sense that the tag explicitly tell you so, too.

BTW, paradigm has a disambiguation page on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm_(disambiguation) it includes separated articles for *paradigm*, an experimental setup, and *programming paradigm*, a style of programming

Comment: Hmm, while we're at it, let's rename [tag:c#] to [tag:programming-in-c#-language]. [tag:xml] can become [tag:programming-with-xml-data]. [tag:ruby] can turn into [tag:ruby-programming-not-gemology] in case anyone's confused about the precious stone by the same name.

Comment: @NathanTuggy  great, lets go strawman. You know that C# is not included in the dictionary. xml neither. Paradigm is a word with a perfectly valid meaning outside software development, heck it's being used with that meaning on software development too, "programming" is just qualifier.

Comment: "C#" is most famously the name of one of the notes in the Western musical scale. "XML", while exclusively a *computer* thing, is *not* something exclusive to programming, as it's entirely possible to ask about XML configuration files on SU, XML formats on any of several data sites like maybe Open Data, and so forth. I'm not trying to strawman here; I really do think that your basic test — can a tag name be used as-is for something off-topic — is either over-simplified or very poorly explained. And I think the pushback this answer is getting shows that this is a common thought.

Comment: @NathanTuggy you know perfectly well that a "XML configuration files on SU" will use the tag for the program that uses the configuration files.